# Detecting extra mouse button click in batch

Tags: batch-file

I'm very new to batch programing, and I was wondering if there is a way to detect when the extra mouse buttons have been clicked in batch.

Comment: what have you tried to do it on your own? Please, show us your efforts, so we can try to help you. You can begin with a nice tool called `google`.

Comment: @elzooilogico no. I have almost no knowledge with batch programing. I only learned as far as simple if cases. I'm more of a C# guy, but NO one on the internet has any good tutorials for mouse hooks. So I'm stuck.

Answer (score 0):

If you are used to c# you may build a program to detect mouse input and pipe input to the batch itself , i.e `getinput.exe | mybatch.cmd`. It's not a trivial thing, but you may see how can be achieved (here with powershell) [Tetris game in a pure Batch file](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6812) by *Aacini*.

You can download a full working `mouse batch menu` test [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6xXrI7w48EObzdISFVwXzQzXzg). `input` and `output` is handled (and written) in `c`, but main processing is pure `batch`.

The following code, is a batch hibryd that creates a `c# executable` if it doesn't exist. You can build `c# code`  as complex as you may need, the issue is two grab `cmd's window input` and process it on the batch file.

```
//>nul 2>nul||@goto :batch_code
/*
:batch_code
@echo off
setlocal

if not exist "%~n0.exe" call :build_the_exe || exit/B

%~n0.exe
endlocal
exit /b 0


:build_the_exe
:: find csc.exe
set "frm=%SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\"
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%v in ('dir /b /a:d  /o:-n "%SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v*"') do (
   set netver=%%v
   goto :break_loop
)
:break_loop
set "csc=%frm%%netver%\csc.exe"
:: csc not found
if "%csc%" == "\csc.exe" echo/&echo/Warning: Net Framework Not Found&exit/B 1
::csc found
call %csc% /nologo /out:"%~n0.exe" "%~dpsfnx0" 
exit/B 0
*/


//begin c# code
public class HelloWorld
{
   public static void Main()
   {
      System.Console.WriteLine("Hello, C# World!");
   }
}
```

Another example

```
//>nul 2>nul||@goto :batch_code
/*
:batch_code
@echo off
setlocal

if not exist "keyTime.exe" call :build_the_exe || exit/B

:: use the newly created exe
<NUL set/p="Press a key (wait 5 seconds) "

keyTime.exe /W 5000
endlocal

exit /b 0


:build_the_exe
:: find csc.exe
set "frm=%SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\"
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%v in ('dir /b /a:d  /o:-n "%SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v*"') do (
   set netver=%%v
   goto :break_loop
)
:break_loop
set "csc=%frm%%netver%\csc.exe"
:: csc not found
if "%csc%" == "\csc.exe" echo/&echo/Warning: Net Framework Not Found&exit/B 1
::csc found
call %csc% /nologo /out:"keyTime.exe" "%~dpsfnx0" 
exit/B 0
*/


//begin c# code
using System;

namespace ElZooilogico
{
  public static class choice
  {
// readkey with timeout     
    private static void ReadKeyTimeout(int msecs, char theChar)
    {
      theChar = '\0';
      ConsoleKeyInfo cfi;
      ReadKeyDelegate d = Console.ReadKey;
      IAsyncResult result = d.BeginInvoke(null, null);
      result.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(msecs);
      if ( result.IsCompleted )
      {
        cfi = d.EndInvoke(result);
        theChar = cfi.KeyChar;
      }
    }
    delegate ConsoleKeyInfo ReadKeyDelegate();    
// readkey with timeout

    [STAThread]
    public static int Main(string[] args)
    {
      char myChar='\0'; int wait = 10000;

      for ( int i = 0; i < args.Length; i++ )
      {
        if ( args[i].Equals("/W", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ) { wait = Int32.Parse(args[i + 1]); }
      }

      ReadKeyTimeout(wait, myChar);
      Console.Write(myChar);

      return 0;
    }
  } // class miClass
} // namespace ElZooilogico
```